# UISlider is not moving in manual way, in iOS 7 and above

Tags: ios, uislider

I am trying to implement a UISlider programmatically inside a toolbar.

Here is my code:

```
audioSliderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 8, 190, 47)];
audioSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 10, 170, 10)];

[audioSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[audioSliderView addSubview:audioSlider];
[audioToolBar addSubview:audioSliderView];
```

Everything is working fine in IOS 6. But when I am trying to move UISlider thumb using manually it stuck some times when using IOS 7 or other highest versions.